# JavaFX - Extra horizontal space in drawing arrows after rotation

Tags: java, javafx, rotation, shapes

I have this part of my code:

```
Group g = new Group();

double xMid = (end.getCenterX() - start.getCenterX())/2;
double yMid = (end.getCenterY() - start.getCenterY())/2;
Line a = new Line(xMid, yMid-4, xMid, yMid+4);
Line b = new Line(xMid, yMid-4, xMid-10, yMid);
Line c = new Line(xMid, yMid+4, xMid-10, yMid);

g.getChildren().add(a);
g.getChildren().add(b);
g.getChildren().add(c);

g.setRotate(getAngle(start, end));
g.setTranslateX(start.getCenterX());
g.setTranslateY(start.getCenterY());
```

The above code is responsible for drawing an arrow in the middle of a line, which goes from `start` to `end` (these are `Circle`s acting as a starting and ending points). The arrow has to be rotated in the proper direction. Here's the output for multiple lines with such arrows:

[image: output]

As you can see, there's a shift to left if angle is close to ±90°.

I [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) that:

> [...] if transforms and effects are set directly on children of this
>   Group, those will be included in this Group's layout bounds.

but it didn't really help me to solve this issue. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I'm confused, what is the translation at the end for? Are you sure the arrows aren't pointing from end to start? As for the shift, did you have a look at the layoutBounds? The pivot of the rotation is the center of the layoutBounds, so if that is not the center of the triangle, that might explain the shift.

Comment: @Lidae Arrow is rotated and then moved to the right place - middle of the line. Hence the translation.

Comment: but they are already in the right place before the translation, unless the arrows point inwards, but then the arrow head is pointing in the wrong way...

Comment: @Lidae No, they are not. Translation (or simply adding `start.getCenterX()` to `xMid`, and `yMid` accordingly) is neccessary.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right! My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all 3 lines that form a triangle are easiest to use `Polygon`.

To fix the pivot point being chosen based on the layout bounds, you could use a `Rotate` transform and a `Translate` transform as `transform`s or simply calculate concatenation of the 2 matrices on your own and use `Affine`:

```
private static final double[] POLYGON_POINTS = {
    -5, -4,
    -5, 4,
    5, 0
};

private static void makeArrow(Pane parent, Circle start, Circle end, double t) {
    Polygon arrow = new Polygon(POLYGON_POINTS);
    arrow.setFill(null);
    arrow.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    double dx = end.getCenterX() - start.getCenterX();
    double dy = end.getCenterY() - start.getCenterY();

    double d = Math.hypot(dx, dy);

    double sin = dy / d;
    double cos = dx / d;

    // matrix:
    //  [  cos     -sin     0    t * dx + start.getCenterX() ]        
    //  [  sin      cos     0    t * dy + start.getCenterY() ]        
    //  [   0        0      1                   0            ]        
    //  [   0        0      0                   1            ]
    Affine affine = new Affine(cos, -sin, t * dx + start.getCenterX(), sin, cos, t * dy + start.getCenterY());

    arrow.getTransforms().add(affine);
    parent.getChildren().add(arrow);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Circle end = new Circle(200, 20, 5);
    Circle start = new Circle(20, 200, 5);
    Line line = new Line(start.getCenterX(), start.getCenterY(), end.getCenterX(), end.getCenterY());

    Pane root = new Pane(line, start, end);

    makeArrow(root, start, end, 0.5);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to create a group containing an upward line and an arrow together and then just rotate this group around center.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Pane root = createPane();
            root.setTranslateX(200);
            root.setTranslateY(200);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Pane createPane() {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        ArrowFactory arrowfactory = new ArrowFactory();
        double lineLength = 100;
        double centerX = 0;
        double centerY = 0;
        root.getChildren().addAll(
            arrowfactory.createLineAndArrow(centerX, centerY, lineLength, 0),
            arrowfactory.createLineAndArrow(centerX, centerY, lineLength, 30),
            arrowfactory.createLineAndArrow(centerX, centerY, lineLength, 45),
            arrowfactory.createLineAndArrow(centerX, centerY, lineLength, 60),
            arrowfactory.createLineAndArrow(centerX, centerY, lineLength, 90),
            arrowfactory.createLineAndArrow(centerX, centerY, lineLength, 135),
            arrowfactory.createLineAndArrow(centerX, centerY, lineLength, 180),
            arrowfactory.createLineAndArrow(centerX, centerY, lineLength, 225),
            arrowfactory.createLineAndArrow(centerX, centerY, lineLength, 270),
            arrowfactory.createLineAndArrow(centerX, centerY, lineLength, 315)
            );
        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

`ArrayFactory.java`:

```
public class ArrowFactory {
    private final int arrowWidth = 10;
    private final int arrowHeight = 10;

    public Group createLineAndArrow(double centerX, double centerY, double lineLength, double rotation) {
        Group group = new Group();

        Line line = new Line(centerX, centerY, centerX, centerY - lineLength);
        Polygon upwardArrow = createUpwardArrow(centerX, centerY - lineLength / 2);

        group.getChildren().addAll(line, upwardArrow);
        group.getTransforms().add(new Rotate(rotation, centerX, centerY));
        return group;
    }

    private Polygon createUpwardArrow(double centerX, double centerY) {
        Polygon arrow = new Polygon(
                createUpwardArrowPoints(centerX, centerY + arrowHeight/2));
        arrow.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        arrow.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        return arrow;
    }

    private double[] createUpwardArrowPoints(double centerX, double centerY) {
        return new double[] {
            centerX - arrowWidth / 2, centerY,  // left
            centerX + arrowWidth / 2, centerY,  // right
            centerX, centerY - arrowHeight,     // top
                };
    }
}
```

[image]

for using circle centers as inputs you could use:

```
private Group createLineAndArrow(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        double distance = Math.hypot(x1-x2, y1-y2);
        double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x2 - x1, y2 - y1));
        return arrowfactory.createLineAndArrow(x1, y1, distance, angle);
}
```